# SQL - Pivot tables with 3 cross tabs

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot-table, crosstab

I have the raw data looks like

```
Class Cert  Name  Benefit  Coverage
------------------------------- 
1     1001  ABC    EHC       Family
1     1001  ABC    DEN       Family
2     1002  XYZ    EHC       Single
2     1002  XYZ    DEN       Single
3     1003  LMN    EHC       Couple
3     1003  LMN    DEN       Couple.
```

I want the final output to look like

```
**Class**                          **Benefit**
        EHC-Single EHC-Couple EHC-Family    DEN-Single DEN-Couple DEN-Family
1                                   1                                 1
2             1                                  1
3                        1                                 1
```

Values below the columns are count of Certificates.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it like below. See in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63776/1)

```
;WITH CTE
 AS (SELECT COUNT(*)                 Counts,
            Class,
            Benefit + '-' + Coverage AS [Benefits]
     FROM   ##MyTemp
     GROUP  BY Class,
               Benefit,
               Coverage)
SELECT Class,
       [EHC-Single],
       [EHC-Couple],
       [EHC-Family],
       [DEN-Single],
       [DEN-Couple],
       [DEN-Family]
FROM   CTE
       PIVOT(MAX(Counts)
            FOR [Benefits] IN ([EHC-Single],
                               [EHC-Couple],
                               [EHC-Family],
                               [DEN-Single],
                               [DEN-Couple],
                               [DEN-Family])) AS TempList;
```

Comment: @user3525244 do show your appreciation by up-voting my answer if it helped you.